# Sequence of invertible operators

Tags: operator-theory, cauchy-sequences

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $(T_n)$ a sequence of bounded invertible operators on $L^p([0,a],X)$ such that :
$$
\sup_n \Vert T_n\Vert < \infty,\sup_n \Vert T_n^{-1} \Vert < \infty
$$
and $(T_n f)$ is a Cauchy sequence for every $f\in L^p([0,a],X)$.
How can we show that the sequence $(T_n^{-1}f)$ is a Cauchy sequence for every $f\in L^p([0,a],X)$. Thank you very much.

EDIT:
I added the condition $\sup_n \Vert T_n^{-1} \Vert < \infty$.

Comment: Is something missing here?  Because this isn't seem true: isn't $T_n f =\frac{1}{n}f$ a counterexample here?

Comment: Surely not.  Take $X = \mathbb R$, $T_nf = f/n$.

Comment: Yes, it is a counterexample and i don't know what can be missed here.

Comment: What if we add this condition $\sup_n \Vert T_n^{-1} \Vert < \infty$.

Comment: That condition is not enough, since the counterexample satisfies that as well.  You need the sup to be independent of n for it to be sufficient.

Comment: I don't think so: in the counterexample we have $T_n^{-1}f = nf$ and then $\Vert T_n^{-1} \Vert = n$. Hence the sup over n does not exist. Am I wrong?